# Issue when running an AWS Lambda Node.js function with a simple Telegram bot example

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, telegram, node-telegram-bot-api

I'm exploring **Telegram bots** and have two **AWS Lambda functions**, one written in Python and another in **Node**.
The Python lambda works fine and is able to send messages to a Telegram chat. However I've tried to do the same with a very simple example in the Node lambda but it does not work. There is no error but **no messages are sent to the chat**.

The repository I'm using is: https://github.com/xoopisoft/aws-lambda-nodejs-telegram-bot/tree/feature/simple-implementation (the chat id and the token are blurred for security reasons)

In summary, there are 2 main components: the `index.js` file with the code and the NPM dependency for `telegram-bot-api`

I know that the bot is correctly setup because the messages work for the same bot from the Python lambda. So probably there is a silly mistake (I'm a Node newbie...). Does someone know what might be the problem? Thanks in advance

Comment: whatis the error? did you checked cloudwatch logs for lambda?

Comment: @JatinMehrotra As mentioned in the description, there is no error, meaning that the Lambda function starts and ends correctly (the start and end date-times are written to the logs) but the message is not sent to the channel.